# Is absolute value a function or property?

Tags: absolute-value

Not the most groundbreaking curiosity, but entertaining my brain.

In basic algebra, is absolute value a function, counting the distance between the value and zero?

Or is it a property, that every numbers unsigned representation is its absolute value?

Comment: In geometrically $|x|$ =$|x-0|$ represents the distance between the value and zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematics does not distinguish between "functions" and "properties" in the way you seem to imagine. The same thing can be called a "function" in one breath and treated like a "property" in the next without anyone batting an eye.

For example, the **arctangent** is undoubtedly a function. Yet we also happily say that **the arctangent of** $1$ is $\pi/4$, suggesting that $\pi/4$ is somehow a property, i.e. something that we can find attached to the number $1$ with the label "arctangent". But I don't think anyone would seriously say that "its arctangent is $\pi/4$" is inherently part of what the number one *really is*.

I suspect you may be thinking of a real number as somehow "made up of" an absolute value together with a sign, which would make the absolute value "morally" more of a "property" of the number than "actangent = $\pi/4$" is a property of $1$.

But most of the time mathematics doesn't even care what numbers "really are". We work from descriptions of how they *behave* -- and surely one of the ways they behave is that for each number we can find a nonnegative number that we call its "absolute value". But what we do with that fact doesn't depend on whether we think of this as a "property" or a "function" -- it doesn't matter whether the absolute value was "inside" the number to begin with or we had to do some computations to find it. Just that the computation *exists* is all we need to know.

(Furthermore, even in the rare cases where we do care how numbers look "inside", the representation we choose for them is almost never a combination of a sign and a magnitude. This has technical reasons. We *could* choose a sign-magnitude representation, but the point here is that *outside* the formal construction of the reals we don't *care* whether one construction or the other was used).

Comment: I was thinking of functions and properties more like a program, although the line can blurred there even. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute value is commonly defined as a **function** $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and in a wider sense also $\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ and can indeed be described as "distance between argument and $0$". It takes nonnegative values, so also $[0,\infty)$ can be practicized as codomain.

A property can be interpreted as a function that takes values in $\{0,1\}$ or $\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$ if you like.

This cannot be said in general of the absolute value, so it is **no property**.

Comment: I don't think you're using "property" in the sense that the OP is using "property".

Comment: @Christopher I think it can be captured in it. In the question of the OP (probably concerning $\mathbb R$) *every* number has the property that the unsigned representation of it equals its absolute value. You can identify that with a function $\mathbb R\to\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$ that takes value $\text{true}$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.